# java.io.IOException:Unable to determine system type - response: 331 Please specify the password

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-jms

We are using the quartz scheduler to run multiple jobs in our `mediation server` project, spring 3.0 framework, hibernate, Apache tomcat. Scheduler jobs begin to start as the tomcat container is loaded. One job executes at a particular instance of time (suppose 1 minute for 1st job and 3 minute for 2nd job) to take the latest cdr file from ftp (using commons-net 2.2 jar and filezilla 3.5.3) to copy onto the local system. We are getting

```
Unable to determine system type response: 331  Please specify the password.
Unable to determine system type response: 530
```

problem when two jobs execute concurrently.

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: are you specify the password for the ftp? or check the username of FTP is right?

Answer (score 2):

If you do a google search for ["331 Please specify the password."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22331%20Please%20specify%20the%20password.%22), you'll see that it's an FTP error which indicates that you're not providing a password.

Here's a [list of FTP error codes](http://www.theegglestongroup.com/writing/ftp_error_codes.php) , which specifies `331` as:

```
331     User name okay, need password.
```